# Error on Rails includes after updating to 4.2.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Rails app that I am upgrading from ruby 2.1.5 and Rails 4.0.x to Ruby 2.2.8 and Rails 4.2.7. After update I have found the following query no longer works:

```
@courses = Course.where(active: true).joins(:course_classes).where(:course_classes => { active: true, class_type: "live"}).includes(:live_class_dates).where('live_class_dates.start_date >= ?', Date.today)
```

It looks like the 'includes' method is the issue. I tried replacing includes with joins, but this looks to be ignoring or incorrectly interpreting the last where clause.

First, is this a Ruby or Rails issue? And second, any suggestions on a query to replace this one?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Here is the entire error I am getting:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "live_class_dates"
LINE 1: ... = $2 AND "course_classes"."class_type" = $3 AND (live_class...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" INNER JOIN "course_classes" ON "course_classes"."course_id" = "courses"."id" WHERE "courses"."active" = $1 AND "course_classes"."active" = $2 AND "course_classes"."class_type" = $3 AND (live_class_dates.start_date >= '2018-06-25')  ORDER BY "courses"."title" ASC
```

Comment: What about it isn't working? No results? An error?

Comment: @DanielWestendorf just updated and added full error being returned.

Comment: Previously rails would interrogate your string query to determine if the table should be included in the query. This is no longer the case. Now if you want to use a string version of `where` with an included table you will need to add `references` such that your query would now be `Course.where(active: true).joins(:course_classes).where(:course_classes => { active: true, class_type: "live"}).includes(:live_class_dates).where('live_class_dates.start_date >= ?', Date.today).references(:live_class_dates)`

Comment: I found that adding `.references(:live_class_dates)` fixes the error. Unless anyone has a better suggestion I will use that.

Comment: @Lumbee nope that is the exact solution

Comment: Haha...I posted right about the time you did. Thanks for confirming what I found. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that adding `.references(:live_class_dates)` to my existing query fixed the issue. Here is the full query for posterity:

```
@courses = Course.where(active: true).joins(:course_classes).where(:course_classes => { active: true, class_type: "live"}).includes(:live_class_dates).where('live_class_dates.start_date >= ?', Date.today).references(:live_class_dates)
```

Comment: There is a note about that in [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods.includes docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes). Check out conditions section

Comment: @MartinZinovsky however the documents are slightly misleading because if you use the hash version of `where` then rails will include the table automagically. e.g. `Post.includes(:comments).where(comments: { id: 12})` would recognize that `comments` is a condition and would ensure that the `comments` table was joined accordingly without the specific `references`